# What does "to vow mentally" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> My sister had become a zombie and I wasn't far from that condition
>   too. So in this particular state she once asked me to feed the babies
>   milk while she goes off for a rejuvenating bath. I nodded half asleep.
>   Few moments later I heard one of the baby crying. I reached for the
>   bottle and put it in his mouth. Dazed I **vowed mentally** to never
>   get married.

Does "mentally" here mean "silently"?
Is "to vow mentally" used in the formal or informal language?

Comment: Effectively, it does mean 'silently' - he _thought_ "I vow never to get married" rather than saying it out loud.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  It means he swore a vow to himself, not out loud or to anyone else